# pylint status code with ignore directives

Tags: python, pylint

The pylint exit status code still returns that an error message was issued (`ret | 2`) even if I explicitly ignore the error with:

```
# pylint: disable=E0611
```

Is there any way I can change this behavior?

Comment: This only occurs in some versions of pylint (it bit me when it started, my "make test"s failed...) and I think it's a bug but I don't know of a way to stop it.  I ended up using make's "ignore return status" stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@torek was right.

The pylint version I was using was 0.25.2.

pylint version 0.28.0 (Current version) works fine.